# Flutter console output message become vertical in android studio Flamingo 2022.2.1

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging, mobile, flutter-debug

For some weird reason, my flutter console output on android studio become vertical text like this :

[image] (see the vertical text on the right side)

It usually showing fine wether I'm using normal log or pretty log

if anyone ever have this problem, please help.

Already try reopen the android studio, setting up the soft warp, but it still the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.